# Count/Statistic for number of SHOW INDEX queries in MySQL/MariaDB 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mariadb

We have a lot of `SHOW INDEX FROM` queries coming from our ORM layer.
Usually there is a mechanism to prevent this but it doesn't seem to work
at the moment. To better analyze the problem it would be helpful if we
could see how many such queries happened on a server.

Is there a counter
or a statistic which can provide us this information?

We use MariaDB 5.5.

Comment: Not only is this a very localized question, the answer was posted to thank the `MariaDB` Discussion Forum ? Seriously ? Since 1) running `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` would have shown this rather quickly, 2) Google could have answered this as well, 3) the MySQL Documentation has it (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html), looking anything starting with `Com_show`, I would just remove this post.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I removed the "thnx"

Comment: @shorty-us-koelle Make sure you disable innodb_stats_on_metadata (set it to 0) or your InnoDB performance will be horrible: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
# mysql -e "show global status like 'Com_show_keys';"
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| Com_show_keys | 12776476 |
+---------------+----------+`
```